# Select @Var into temp table

Tags: sql-server, variables, stored-procedures, temp-tables

In my procedure I am loading declared variables with values then trying to put the variables into a temp table. I am doing this:

```
select cast(@rec_cnt as varchar(5), @tbl_name
INTO #TEMP_TBL_DUP_CNT
```

But keep getting msg: Incorrect syntax near ','. That is, the comma between columns is causing an issue when I try execute proc. What is wrong with this statement?

I've checked temp table doesn't already exist as it shouldn't anyway.

I just ran a similar query to load the table data into a temp table and that worked. Can I not used directly the declared variable values, if so what do I do otherwise?

EDIT: Also wanted to ask how can I query this temp table. I understand I need to do it in scope of the SP, what kind of variable can I load all the result into? I was thinking that I would need to select into the variable from temp table then print?

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: count the parentheses.

Comment: You missed to close `cast`. i.e) `)` is required after `varchar(5)`.

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed this after posting !! I also had to cast both variables to varchar as it was still complaining.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing your closing parenthesis on your `cast`:

```
                                  |
                                  v
select cast(@rec_cnt as varchar(5)), @tbl_name
INTO #TEMP_TBL_DUP_CNT
```

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed this after posting !! I also had to cast both variables to varchar as it was still complaining.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE     
    @rec_cnt INT=1,
    @tbl_name INT=2

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP_TBL_DUP_CNT') IS NOT NULL
    Drop table #TEMP_TBL_DUP_CNT

CREATE table #TEMP_TBL_DUP_CNT(rec_cnt  varchar(5),tbl_name varchar(5))
    INSERT INTO #TEMP_TBL_DUP_CNT
    SELECT cast(@rec_cnt as varchar(5)), @tbl_name
```

Comment: I've used the drop table at the start of the script. For the first table have used INSERT..INTO temp then for each subsequent table have used select..into temp as already created.